# Proof check - if $S \subseteq m$ is a collection of sets with positive measure and has $\mu(A_i \cap A_j) = 0$ for all $i \ne j$, then it's countable.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X,m,\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $S \subseteq m$ be a
> collection of sets with the following property: For all $A,B \in S$
> such that $A \ne B$, $\mu(A \cap B) = 0$. Suppose that $\mu(A) > 0$
> for all $A \in S$, and that $\mu$ is a finite measure ($\mu(A) <
>  \infty$ for all $A \in m$). Prove $S$ is a countable set.

**My attempt:**
We've previously proven that if $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of measurable sets with $\mu(A_i \cap A_j)=0$ for all $i \ne j$, then it's $\sigma$-additive:

$$
\mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n) 
$$

We'll use this property in the proof.
Define the following set:

$$
s_0=\{A \in S : \mu(A) \ge 1\}
$$

And for all $n \in \mathbb N $:
$$
s_n = \{A \in S : \frac{1}{n+1} \le \mu(A) \lt \frac{1}{n} \}
$$

Clearly $\cup_{n=0}^{\infty}s_n=S$, since $S$ has positive measure. Suppose there exists $n \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ such that $s_n$ is of infinite cardinality. Then it has a countable subset, so we can construct  a sequence $(A_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ out of it. Since $\cup_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m \subseteq \cup_{A \in s_n}A$, we have $\mu(\cup_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m) \le \mu(\cup_{A \in s_n}A)$. But from the property mentioned above (which implies $(A_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ is also $\sigma$-additive) $\mu(\cup_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_m)$. And since $\mu$ is finite we have:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_m) = \mu (\cup_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m) \le \mu(\cup_{A \in s_n}A) \le \mu(\cup_{A \in S}A) \lt \infty
$$

But $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_m)$ does not converge, since it's either an infinite sum of values that are greater than $1$ (case where $n=0$) or it's greater than the infinite sum $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$ which does not converge (case where $n \gt 0$) - a contradiction. So $s_n$ is finite for all $n\in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ and since $S=\cup_{n=0}^{\infty}s_n$ it is a countable union of finite sets, which is countable.

Comment: You are mostly correct. A small note is that $\cup_{A \in s_n} A$ does not have to be measurable, since it could be an uncountable union. The same goes for $\cup_{A \in S} A$. But you could just directly say $\mu(\cup_{m=1}^\infty A_m) < \infty$ and the proof would be fine.

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you!